# Java: groupingBy subvalue as value

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

Let's say, I have an object Person with fields of type FirstName and LastName. Now I also have a `List<Person>` and I like to use streams.

Now I want to generate a `Map<FirstName, List<LastName>>` in order to group people with the same first name. How do I go about this without writing much code? My approach so far is

```
personList
.stream()
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
    Person::getFirstName,
    person -> person.getLastName() // this seems to be wrong
));
```

but it seems this is the wrong way to assign the value of the map. What should I change? Or should I perhaps use .reduce with `new HashMap<FirstName, List<LastName>>()` as initial value and then aggregate to it by putting elements inside?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
personList.stream()
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
               Person::getFirstName,
               Collectors.mapping(Person::getLastName, Collectors.toList())));
```

You are looking for a downstream collector with `groupingBy`

Answer (score 12):

This should work for you :

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = personList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getFirstName, 
                        Collectors.mapping(Person::getLastName, Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List>> map = personList.stream()
  .collect(groupingBy(Person::getFirstName, groupingBy(Person::getLastName)));
```

The double grouping gives you a map of a map. That's the trick.

Comment: Thank you, but the value was supposed to be a simple list, not another map.